# sticky sidebar doesnt work react

Tags: css, reactjs, sidebar

I am trying to implement a sticky sidebar on my react application but it is not working.
I tried implementing `position:sticky` but it didnt work at all.Here is my code

On my sidebar.js

```
<Container className="content">
  <Row>     
    <Col xs="3">
      <div className="sidebar" />
    </Col>
    <Col xs="6">
      <div className="postcontent" />
    </Col>
    <Col xs="3">
      <div className="sidebar" />
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

On my app.css

```
.sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Did you try this: `position: fixed` ??

Comment: `position: sticky` is not well supported  https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky whereas `fixed` as mentioned by @Jed is

Comment: 900px is a very large value, do you have big enough screen?